# How to prevent your custom .gitignore file to be overridden?

Tags: magento2, composer

Running `composer install` I have my `.editorconfig` and `.gitignore` overriding.

Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

Since Magento 2.4.6 it doesn't happen anymore, but if you're running an older version, you can ignore it in the **magento-deploy-ignore** section.

```
{
    ...
    "extra": {
        "magento-deploy-ignore": {
            "*": [
                "/.gitignore"
            ]
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento-composer-installer/blob/master/doc/Deploy.md#how-to-prevent-your-custom-gitignore-file-to-be-overridden